# jQuery Form Plugin - File upload bug

Tags: jquery, html, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to use the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) to achieve an "ajax like" file upload, and it is working correctly in Chrome, but I'm getting an odd bug in Firefox.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form action="upload.php" action="POST" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="file">

    <input type="submit" value="Upload">

</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#upload').ajaxForm({                 
    beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
    success: SubmitSuccesful,
    error: AjaxError                               
});

    function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
      var queryString = $.param(formData);
      alert('BeforeSend method: \n\nAbout to submit: \n\n' + queryString);
      return true;
    }

    function AjaxError() {
      alert("An AJAX error occured.");
    }

    function SubmitSuccesful(responseText, statusText) {        
      //alert("SuccesMethod:\n\n" + responseText);
      $('#output').html('<img src="'+responseText+'">');
    }
```

As expected, in Chrome after selecting a file and clicking Upload, the file is uploaded and then displayed, without a page reload - but in Firefox, the upload.php script (the script that actually uploads the image and returns the path) is downloaded, in full php to my local machine.

Any ideas would be appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the mime-types in the request and response headers? You can do that by opening up firebug in firefox. You can see the request and response header in the 'Net'-tab.